# Google analytics: Complete a goal when two events occur

Tags: google-analytics

There are two events.

1. User visit `/point1`.
2. User visit `/point2`.

If the events occur in this order, I want the goal to be hit.

I have created a funnel for this, but the problem is that even if the user does not visit `/point1`, and visit `/point2`, the goal is hit! (destination is point2..)

I want the goal to be hit only when the user visit `/point1` and `/point2` in that order.How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you can't (not via configuration, that is). Funnels only affect the visualisation, not goal completion.

You can either do a workaround in code - set a cookie on `/point1`, then fire an event on `/point2` only when the cookie is set, and change your configuration to use an event based goal.

If you do not need to actual goal conversion, but just want to know how many users completed the steps in the correct order, you can create a segment of the "sequence" type (step1 page equals /point1 followed by step2 page equals /point2), which will limit the data displayed in the standard reports to sessions where users visited one point after the other.

Comment: Thanks! it somewhat helped me. But, what if user redirects to an another website after `/point1` and that new website calls `/point2`.

Comment: This is my scenario. The cookie is not migrated to another website when the user redirects. Please suggest, what can I do now?

Comment: No /point1 and /point2 are on same domain, user redirects after /point1 and then from other website /point2 was called.

Comment: even then it worked. Thanks a lot! There was a typo.